# Calculating with terms in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mathematical-optimization

Calculating with terms in JavaScript

I am currently developing a triangle calculator which will calculate everything in a triangle if enough information is available.

It would be good if instead of decimal numbers with rounding inaccuracies, it would display the numbers as fractions and root terms.

For example, instead of 1.4142135623730951, √2 should be represented.

But mathjs can't even simplify √3 * √3 correctly, the result is 2.99999999999996 instead of 3.

Is it at all possible to represent terms as accurately as possible with the help of a library?

Comment: This seems a valid question, why the downvotes?

Comment: Is this a question about accuracy or about a visual presentation? Because nothing really changes for the final result. In JavaScript one has to deal/live with floating point accuracy.